# Update activity UI from service when activity became visible

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

Am having an activity that will start service, service will download something from internet and i have to update activity UI.

but consider below cases

1. If my activity is alive i have to update activity UI without broadcast receiver, What is the best way to do this.?
2. If my activity is not alive and when it comes alive/foreground then i have to update UI with service result, How to do this.? (without saving into DB)

Comment: I guess thats the only way I know.

Answer (score 1):

Let me drop my suggestions point by point,

1. Yes you can achieve it by [EventBus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-the-eventbus-library--cms-22694) (or) interface. Coming to eventbus, it is similar to broad cast receiver.
2. When the activity is not alive, you are fetching the data and when coming to alive you had to update the UI. In order to do that somehow you had to save the value somewhere either internally or externally (OR) you had to fetch the values from the internet whenever the activity comes to alive.